# Fastest way for comparing two tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables with a structure like this

```
Table 1 
tid | population
1   | 50
2   | 55
3   | 45

Table 2
tid | population
1   | 50
2   | 60
3   | 40
```

I must compare these two tables and find out which ones hasn't changed (in this case i should only find tid 1)

I can create 2 arrays for looping but since each table has more than 40k records. I'm looking for easier, faster way!

Edit.
Looks like i should use joins. What I've tried to do is as follows.
Ps. Table 1 name is 2016-5-20 Table 2 name 2016-05-21

```
 $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT `2016-5-20.tid`, `2016-5-20.population`
 FROM    `2016-5-20`
 JOIN    `2016-05-21` ON 2016-5-20.tid = 2016-05-21.tid AND 2016-5-20.population = 2016-05-21.population');
 $sth->execute();
 $result2 = $sth->fetchAll(); 
 print_r($result2);
```

Comment: Your query != answer query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select `t1`.`id` from `table1` as `t1`,`table2` as `t2` 
 where `t1`.`id`=`t2`.`id` and `t1`.`population`<>`t2`.`population`
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8958b/1)

Answer (score 4):

You could just join them:

```
SELECT t1.tid, t1.population
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   table2 t2 ON t1.tid = t2.tid AND t1.population = t2.population
```

Comment: My table 1 is named: 2016-5-20
And Table 2 named: 2015-05-21
I've created this code with your answer. But sadly it throws an error.
Note: I will edit my original post with this code so you can read. :)